# Not getting a production build in create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app

I have a project using **create-react-app**.

I had no probelm working on it in developement mode (using **scripts/start**). After working on my project for a few weeks, I wanted to deploy for production.

I ran **scripts/build**.

This created a folder structure that looks like this :

[image]

I assume that the **index.html** is the entry point for all this so I ran index.html.

All I get is a blank screen with some 404 errors.

[image]

I have absolutely no idea what this means..!

I tried to have a look at the **index.html** file but it just contains obfuscated javascript. (create-react-app seems to hide everything that might be helpful in solving a problem).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.a5508311.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>!function (l) {
    function e(e) {
        for (var r, t, n = e[0], o = e[1], u = e[2], f = 0, i = []; f < n.length; f++) t = n[f], p[t] && i.push(p[t][0]), p[t] = 0;
        for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (l[r] = o[r]);
        for (s && s(e); i.length;) i.shift()();
        return c.push.apply(c, u || []), a()
    }
```

How do I get my create-react-app from developement into production?

**UPDATE:**

I decided to update my generated index.html file and put a '.' in front of my paths.

```
<script src="/static/js/1.e82eda2e.chunk.js"></script>
```

becomes :

```
<script src="./static/js/1.e82eda2e.chunk.js"></script>
```

Now it works (kind of). So much for this being an out of the box solution!!

How do I prevent my paths being messed up in create-react-app when generating the production build index.html? And why is it doing this in the first place??!

**UPDATE 2:**

Digging around the internet I found out that you can add

```
  "homepage": "./",
```

I did this.

Now my application works, but the images are not loading. Also my react routing is broken. Refreshing links does not work....

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do this is to simply run it locally using serve:

1. npm install serve -g
2. npm run build
3. serve -s build

This will create a local server running on port 5000 at http://localhost:5000

Comment: but i want to run it in production. i want to put it in my public folder on my web server.